# EEA permanent residency denied for my non-EEA daughter

Tags: residence-cards

I am from Germany, my 19-year-old daughter is Ugandan.

I applied for a permanent residency and, since my daughter was about to travel, we did not apply together.

I got my PR within months, but hers took 5 months, and has been rejected. They said we did not provide the documents required. On her application form, I stated that all the documents had been provided in my own application, and that she was applying as my dependent. I did not think they would need the same documents a few months after I applied.

Should she appeal, which costs £80.00, or reapply?

Comment: To which country did you apply (was it UK as you note the cost in pounds)?

Comment: Reapply is probably quicker. Did you include a document with a list of the documents submitted? This is always handy and makes thier job easier. You can also reference it on the application, each of which is often considered separately. You are German but you are certain that your daugher is not?

Comment: As there has been no update to this, it is unclear what the resolution should be.